# Deep RL to find maximum of a function with definition range (PyTorch or Tensorflow)

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, pytorch, neural-network, reinforcement-learning

I have an unknown two-dimensional **blackbox** function f(x,y)=z. The Agent does not know the function term, but it can get the output z by inserting x and y in the function.

The agent is like a hiker who walks on the terrain. The two-dimensional functions output different heights (z) which you could see as a terrain.

The agent always starts at a random location. The location consists of a random x and a random y value (only integers).

The maximum value of the function within the definition range is also known. For Example the definition range for x and y is between -100 and 100. The maximum value z=143 is located at x=-23 and y=42.

**The agent can perform the following actions:**

- move left (input values: x=x-1 , y=y)
- move right (input values: x=x+1, y=y)
- move up (input values: x=x , y=y+1)
- move down (input values: x=x , y=y-1)

**Rewards for the agent:**

- -1 per step unless other rewards are triggered
- +100 if the maximum value was found

I would like to train a neural network (agent) to solve this problem. I think the neural network should have 2 inputs for the current x and y location of the agent. I also think there should be 4 outputs as there are 4 actions.

Is it possible to do something like this with PyTorch or Tensorflow? I mean it's almost like the agent would walk on a grid. Does anyone can show me a good example code to do something like this without using other libraries such as gym/gymnasium? :)

I would appreciate it if someone could help me with this.

I also tried to create something like this with chatgpt:

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.optim as optim
import torch.nn.functional as F
import random

device = torch.device("cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")

class QNetwork(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(QNetwork, self).__init__()
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(2, 128)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(128, 64)
        self.fc3 = nn.Linear(64, 4)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = F.relu(self.fc1(x))
        x = F.relu(self.fc2(x))
        return self.fc3(x)

class Agent:
    def __init__(self):
        self.q_network = QNetwork()
        self.optimizer = optim.Adam(self.q_network.parameters(), lr=0.9)
        self.gamma = 0.95

    def select_action(self, state):
        with torch.no_grad():
            q_values = self.q_network(state)
        return torch.argmax(q_values).item()

def calculate_function_value(x, y):
    return 2-x^(2)-y^(2)-2*y-2*x

agent = Agent()
num_episodes = 1000
MAX_VALUE = 3.8 # example

for episode in range(num_episodes):
    print("Episode: ", episode)

    x, y = random.uniform(-100, 100), random.uniform(-100, 100)
    state = torch.tensor([x, y], dtype=torch.float32)
    total_reward = 0

    while True:
        action = agent.select_action(state)
        print("Action: ", action)
        if action == 0:
            x -= 1
            if x < -100:
                x = -100
        elif action == 1:
            x += 1
            if x > 100:
                x = 100
        elif action == 2:
            y -= 1
            if y < -100:
                y = -100
        elif action == 3:
            y += 1
            if y > 100:
                y = 100

        new_state = torch.tensor([x, y], dtype=torch.float32)
        z = calculate_function_value(x, y)

        reward = -1
        if z >= MAX_VALUE:
            reward = 100
            agent.q_network.eval()
        total_reward += reward

        # updating Q-Values and calculation of loss
        with torch.no_grad():
            max_future_q = reward + agent.gamma * torch.max(agent.q_network(new_state))
        current_q = agent.q_network(state)[action]
        loss = F.mse_loss(current_q, max_future_q)
        
        # Optimization
        agent.optimizer.zero_grad()
        loss.backward()
        agent.optimizer.step()

        state = new_state

        if z >= MAX_VALUE:
            break
    
    print(f"Episode {episode + 1}, Total Reward: {total_reward}")
```